# Define Simple MATLAB Class

Tags: matlab

I am a Microsoft developer but trying to assist someone with some MATLAB code and design. I'm struggling to understand the syntax and usage of a class definition.

Code so far:

```
classdef Person

   properties
      Name 
   end

   methods

       function obj = Person(aName)
          obj.Name = aName;
       end

       function ret = IsGraeme(obj)
           if STRCMP( obj.Name , 'Graeme')
               ret= 1;
           else
               ret= 0;
           end
       end
   end
end
```

Now, I expect my usage to be similar to below:

```
graeme = Person('Graeme');
graeme.IsGraeme();
```

with the last line returning `1`.

The first line of usage results in an error:

> Too many inputs

The samples I have found on MATLAB seem to give you the `classdef` but not the usage.

I hope someone can help correct this simple example so that I can continue to build on it.  (As mentioned, I am an experienced dev, just not in this language!).

**UPDATE 1:**

Using MATLAB 2013b.

Exact usage and resultant error below:

```
>> gt = Person('Graeme')
Error using Person
Too many input arguments.
```

Comment: If I copy&paste your code, and change `STRCMP` to `strcmp` (MATLAB is [mostly] case-sensitive!), this works as you described. Do you use exactly the same code snippet? What MATLAB version and operating system are you working with?

Comment: Using 2013b on windows 7. Will try changing case when back at desk. Thanks for fast reply.

Comment: Confirmed that changing STRCMP to strcmp does not make this work.

Comment: @GinjaNinja there is definitely a difference between what you have posted here and what you have on your own machine. The only other option is that maybe you have a different file named `Person.m` on your path? Check with `which('Person')`. Also, maybe explicitly inherit from MATLAB's `handle` class?

Comment: The only problem I can think of, is that you haven't named your class file `Person.m`.

Comment: Have you tried simply running `clear` in the  command line, running the code again, and seeing if you get the same error? As everyone else is mentioning, the code itself looks fine as it is.

Comment: *`clear classes` also helps, although MATLAB should issue warning about that...warnings you can also switch off :)  @Suever: handle class just affects copying behavior, should not be a problem here

Comment: OK - so I copy and pasted into a new machine and it works (proving no difference in code). Then seeing @VladislavMartin comment, tried 'Clear' and problem solved!  Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's solution ended up being running the `clear` command in MATLAB. In all likelihood, what happened is an old class definition was already stored in memory and for some reason was not automatically updated. Anyhow - an easy fix!

Just in case others who stumble on this question what an explanation of the simplest basics of class constructors...

In MATLAB, you can an instance of a class without a constructor function, you follow the approach shown [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example--representing-structured-data.html#f2-74210), summed up below:

```
>> gt = Person();
>> gt.Name = 'Graeme';
>> gt.IsGraeme();
```

The OP wanted to create a constructor so that he could assign values to the class object's properties at initialization. Just for clarity's sake, a constructor is:

> a method having the same name as the class.

The below (*modified to fit OP's use-case*) code is essentially copied from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example--representing-structured-data.html#f2-74277). The only difference here is that we first check whether an input value has been provided before attempting to assign a (*potentially undefined*) value to a property of the instantiated class object:

```
function gt = Person(aName)
    if nargin > 0 % Check if more than 0 arguments are provided
        gt.Name = aName; % Assign input argument to property
    end
end
```

Now (as before), `gt = Person('Graeme')` will work as expected. This obviously assumes that the class is saved in a properly named M-file and that you've run `clear` to get rid of previous variable assignment mistakes.